# IPython Notebook - Python Debugger set_trace() is not working when used outside function definition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pdb

When I use set_trace outside a function definition, then I get unexpected results.

[image]

However, when I use set_trace inside a function definition, then it works as expected.

[image]

**Question:** How can I get set_trace working outside a function definition?